# Putting latitude/longitude pairs into JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having some difficulty with putting map waypoints (lat/long pairs) into a JSON array.

Here's what I have so far.

```
var llData = {};
var waypointData = {};


    for (i = 0; i < routeArray.length; i++) { 
        llData['waypoint'+i] = [{"latitude" : routeArray[i].latLng.lat},{"longitude" : routeArray[i].latLng.lng}];
    waypointData.push = llData;
}
```

The above code snippet iterates through multiple latitude/long pairs and should add them all to the waypointData array. However, what I'm getting back is:

```
{"push":{"waypoint1":[{"latitude":-27.47577},{"longitude":153.01693}]}}
```

This is only the last (of four) lat long pairs.

Comment: You're saving each `waypoint` in the property `waypointData.push`. Looks like `waypointData` should be an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

`waypointData.push = llData;`

should be:

`waypointData.push(llData);`

then change `var waypointData = {};` into an array like so:

`var waypointData = [];`

or alternatively keep it as an associative array and use `i` as a key.

`waypointData[i]=llData;`